# Selenium run chrome in mobile mode

Tags: google-chrome, testing, selenium

Is there any possibility to run mobile version of chrome using ChromeDriver in Selenium, I mean something like emulation in Inspect element options?

Comment: are you trying to run something on mobile web? if so, you can try changing the user-agent when you launch your webdriver to simulate the browser running on a phone.

Answer (score 1):

Try --window-size=360,640 option, full option [list](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/)

Answer (score 0):

I think Appium can run against mobile Chrome for Android, via emulation of some description. But I've never run it myself so can't offer more than a general pointer in that direction. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking to emulate mobile chrome for inspection purposes, you could always use the normal computer version of Chrome and set it to emulate a mobile device.  To access the emulation settings, press F12 then click the Show Drawer button and then the Emulation tab.

If you're looking to run scripts against mobile Chrome, then you'll need to use something like Appium as the previous answer suggested.